# How do most people do console.log debugging in Python?

Tags: python, class, debugging, object, tostring

In Node.js when I want to quickly check the value of something rather than busting out the debugger and stepping through, I quickly add a console.log(foo) and get a beautiful:

```
{
   lemmons: "pie",
   number: 9,
   fetch: function(){..}
   elements: {
      fire: 99.9
   }
}
```

Very clear! In Python I get this:

```
class LinkedList:
  head = None
  tail = None
  lemmons = 99
```

`<__main__.LinkedList instance at 0x105989f80>`
or with `vars()`,

`{}`

or with `dir()`,

`['_LinkedList__Node', '__doc__', '__module__', 'append', 'get_tail', 'head', 'lemmons', 'remove', 'tail']`

Yuck! Look at all that nonsense - I thought python was supposed to be fast, beautiful and clean? Is this really how people do it? Do they implement customer **str** and custom **repr** for everything? Because that seems kind of crazy too..

Comment: You say Python's logging is ugly? Have you ever tried to debug C++? :)

Comment: Instance variables go in `__init__`, not at class level. That's why you got such useless output from `vars`.

Comment: I would recommend writing a custom `__repr__`, though.

Comment: @user2357112 wow yeah.. that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: I just print those attributes that I'm interested in, outputting absolutely everything like node.js seems to do would be way too much clutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can print your objects & Python classes in a lot of different ways, here's a simple one:

```
class LinkedList:
    head = None
    tail = None
    lemmons = 99

    def __str__(self):
        return str(vars(LinkedList))

print LinkedList()
```

I'd recommend you start for getting familiar with [**str** and **repr**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) operators. In any case, this is a little example and with python there are tons of ways to pretty print object & classes

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is that you [implement your own `__str__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#using-arbitrary-objects-as-messages) so that you can pick what is important to log in your diags.

However, there is the option to log the whole object dictionary in a "pretty" format using a couple of lines of code.  For example:

```
from pprint import pformat

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1
        self.bar = {"hello": "world"}
        self._private = 0

a = A()
print pformat(vars(a))
# You can also pass pformat to your logger if that's what you have.
```

This will return something like this (depending on how much data you have and thw `width` constraint):

```
{'_private': 0,
 'bar': {'hello': 'world'},
 'foo': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expound on the above answers, mainly the one explaining **str** . Python **repr**() function returns the object representation in string format. This method is called when repr() “super class of **str**” function is invoked on the object. If possible, the string returned should be a valid Python expression that can be used to reconstruct the object again.

This will enhance your logs 10 fold if you implement this method well in any object